# How to resize nyroModal once content height/width has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, nyromodal

I am using nyroModal to show a modal window. It works fine when the initial content is showed. But in the content I have a jQuery toggle method, that makes visible other sections.

I want the modal to auto resize to the new content area. How can I implement that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but nyroModal listens for window resize events to resize the modal, so maybe triggering one yourself could help here. E.g.

```
$(window).resize();
```

However if the "modal window" is an iframe, then nyroModal won't know what size to resize the modal to.

Answer (score 2):

Run this javascript:

```
$.nyroModalSettings({
  width: 645,
  height: 410,
  windowResizing: true
});
```

And your `nyroModal` will be resized (animated)